# Creating a new dataframe where some rows are expanded versions of a single row in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which looks like this

```
             Population Teams          Ad Market
New York Area   1400    Yankees, Mets   10400
Tampa Bay       100     Rays            200
Pittsburg       200     Phillies        500
```

I want to create a new DataFrame which looks like this

```
     Population  Team     Ad Market      Region
0     1400       Yankees    10400      New York Area
1     1400        Mets      10400      New York Area
2     100         Rays       200       Tampa Bay
3     200         Phillies   500       Pittsburg
```

I.e If `Teams` column in a row has `N` values in it, I want the new dataframe to have `N + 1` rows where all columns except Teams are identical, `Team` column in each row has a single value from the original `Teams` column and a `Region` column set to index name of the row in the original dataframe

I want to then join this data frame with another dataframe that has information on a per team basis and do some further analysis.

My current solution is below.  Seems to work but I am essentially doing a bunch of `for loops`.  Wondering if there is a better way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

def splitdf(next_row):
    base_df = pd.DataFrame(next_row.to_dict(), index=[next_row.name]).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Region'})
    base_df.drop('Teams', axis='columns', inplace=True)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for next_team in next_row.Teams.split(', '):
        base_df['Team'] = next_team
        new_df = new_df.append(base_df)
    return new_df
        


df = pd.DataFrame({'Population' : [1400, 100, 1000], 
                   'Teams' : ['Yankees, Mets, Brooklyn', 'Rays', 'Giants, Athletics'], 
                   'Ad Market' : [10400, 2000, 8400]},
                  index = ['New York Area', 'Tampa Bay', 'SF Bay Area'])

new_df = pd.concat(splitdf(df.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df)))
new_df.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'Population' : [1400, 100, 1000],
                   'Teams' : ['Yankees, Mets, Brooklyn', 'Rays', 'Giants, Athletics'],
                   'Ad Market' : [10400, 2000, 8400]},
                  index = ['New York Area', 'Tampa Bay', 'SF Bay Area'])

# split
res = df.assign(Teams=df['Teams'].str.split(', '))

# reset index
res.index.name = 'Region'
res = res.reset_index()

# explode and reset index
out = res.explode('Teams')
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
          Region  Population      Teams  Ad Market
0  New York Area        1400    Yankees      10400
1  New York Area        1400       Mets      10400
2  New York Area        1400   Brooklyn      10400
3      Tampa Bay         100       Rays       2000
4    SF Bay Area        1000     Giants       8400
5    SF Bay Area        1000  Athletics       8400
```

As an alternative, suggested by @wwnde, do:

```
# split
res = df.assign(Teams=df['Teams'].str.split(', '))

# explode and reset index
out = res.explode('Teams').rename_axis(index='Region').reset_index()
print(out)
```

Comment: Maybe another shorter way `df.explode('Teams').rename_axis(index='Region').reset_index()`

Comment: Great answer, @Dani. Learnt a lot by looking up `assign` and `explode`

Comment: @wwnde Teams is not a list just a comma separated string

Comment: @Arvind Swaminathan I asummed `df['Teams']=df['Teams'].str.split(',')` is already done

Answer (score 1):

Convert Teams column to list

```
df['Teams'] = df['Teams'].str.split(',')
```

Assuming Region column is in the index, first reset index and then use the explode function

```
df.reset_index(name ='Region').explode('Teams')
```

And strip of trailing spaces in Teams column

```
df['Teams'] = df['Teams'].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['Teams']=[i.split(',') for i in df['Teams']]
df=df.explode('Teams')
```